# How to install a Facebook app from an external website?

Tags: facebook

I'm planning a new project which is based on a Facebook app.

Users would come to a website to register and set their preferences up.

Then they'd need to install the app to their fan page and it would show as they set it up.

I know it is possible to implement a "button" (or link) which, when clicked, take the user to a facebook page that let them choose the page they want the app to be installed on. (Exemple : here at 3:24 http://vimeo.com/17182109)

What the process to do that ? Is there a Facebook API ? Is it simply a link like http://facebook.com/add?appid=0123456789 ?

Thanks
JB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

When user clicks on install button, redirect page to : 
http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key="your_api_key"&pages

Refer to this for more details.

http://facebookappsnotes.blogspot.com/2011/09/how-do-facebook-page-owners-can-install.html